# rewrite Underbar - memoize

Tags: javascript

While I was woking on rewriting _.memoize and looking up what it means, unfortunately I found out the answer of it by accident.
 However I couldn't understand the code below. I've understood all except for 'key' assignment. Here is the code

```
_.memoize = function(func) {
var cache = {};
var key = arguments.length + Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, ",");
  if( key in cache ) {
    return cache[key];
  } else {
    return cache[key] = func.apply(this, arguments);
  }
};
};
```

Up to now, I've been guessing that 'key' is to make a unique key in cache. 
Could anyone can explain what the 'key' is? I would be really helpful for me.

Comment: It's a pretty dumb attempt at [hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) the arguments into a unique string. E.g. it can distinguish `x(1)` from `x(2)`, or `x(1, 2)` from `x([1, 2])`, but fails to distinguish `x(1, [2, 3])` from `x([1, 2], 3)`.

Comment: Looks like the code is missing a `return function() {`?